# Many to many with extra foreign key?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, many-to-many, code-first

I want to generate a junction table between user and post and I want to have the userId in the post table.

I have this code

```
public class Post
{
    public Post()
    {
        this.ApplicationUser = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
    }

    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime MessageDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; } //this is the problem

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

   public ApplicationUser()
   {
       this.Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
   }

   public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

I get the extra junction table and many-to-many relation between user and post. But this is wrong.

```
   public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

This generates two UserId in the post table (applicationUser_id and User_id) and Post_PostId in the User table. I just want one extra field in the Post table, FK UserId.

I want three tables like this

**Post**

PostId
Message
Date
*UserId FK*

**User**

UserId
And the rest of the fields in asp.net identity user

**UserPosts**

UserId
PostId

Comment: check my updated code

Answer (score 0):

**User table**

```
public partial class User
{

 public User()
 {
     this.Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
     this.UserPosts = new HashSet<UserPost>();
 }

 public int UserId { get; set; }
 public string Username { get; set; }

 public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

 public virtual ICollection<UserPost> UserPosts { get; set; }
}
```

**Post table**

```
public partial class Post
{
 public Post()
 {
     this.UserPosts = new HashSet<UserPost>();
 }

 public int PostId { get; set; }
 public string Message { get; set; }
 public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
 public Nullable<int> UserId { get; set; }

 public virtual User User { get; set; }

 public virtual ICollection<UserPost> UserPosts { get; set; }
}
```

and your mapping table, like this 
your column 1) Id (pk), 2) UserId (fk) 3) PostId (fk)

using entity framework table have one primary key necessary.

**UserPost table**

```
public partial class UserPost
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public Nullable<int> UserId { get; set; }
 public Nullable<int> PostId { get; set; }

 public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
 public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

**Updated Code**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().ToTable("userid table name");
```

this line add in below method of this class **ApplicationDbContext**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{


}
```

Comment: Do explicitly have to set up user UserPost to get a foreign key in posts? If you look att my code, it generate a userPost table and many-to-many relation and its works fine. The problem is to add a FK key to asp.net identity user in the post table. Can see you use the similar code "public virtual User User { get; set; }" in the post class but its not working for me.

Comment: Your code works but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. You create a new class User but I want to use Applicationuser. A user-table (AspNetUser) is automatically created when you create a new project with asp.net Identity, I want to use that already generated table. See my first post. The problem is to get that UserId in the post table. Something like public string Id { get; set; } is not working.

Comment: yaaa i understand. let me try with your requirement.